# Symfony2 Admin Generator error

Tags: symfony

I'm getting the following error while try to setup admin from console

`php app/console admin:setup`

symfony call to undefined method nodeBuilder::append();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user654127 you must know which version you work with,for symfony 2.0 you use 2.0 branch and for symfony 2.1 you use the master branch,